# Can you set a column equal to another column in a table using SQLiteDatabse update()?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

I need to make a column equal to another column in the table. I can't figure it out using the update method of my SQLiteDatabase.

I know the SQL statement is:

```
UPDATE coolTable SET columnA = columnB;
```

Do I put it in the ContentValues I pass the function? or the selection string?

Comment: thanks. I got it to work using the content resolver's update, but I was wondering if it is possible to use the database's update() function instead of execSQL(). It says in the documentation: " you're encouraged to use insert(String, String, ContentValues), update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]), et al, when possible."

Comment: no, you cannot use `update` in that particular case - it is used for syntax like `update tableName set column_1 = new_value_1, ...` where `new_value_1` is a constant value passed in `ContentValues`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `update()` only to set literal values (as bind params), not any other kind of expression supported by [sqlite SQL syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

Use `execSQL()` to execute your raw `UPDATE` query with column name expression.

Answer (score 0):

`execSQL()` with error checking:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

try {
    long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "pweb");
    db.execSQL("update pweb set h_id = _id;");
    long rows = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT changes()", null);
    if(count != rows ) Log.e("wrong count","update failed");
 }
catch(SQLException e){
  Log.e("SQLException","update failed");            
}  

db.close();
```

> but I was wondering if it is possible to use the database's update()
>   function instead of execSQL()

You can use [`sqlite3`](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) to view and manipulate you data, and test out `sql` commands.

Create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE pweb (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,h_id  INTEGER ,sent  INTEGER);
```

See the original rows:

```
sqlite> select * from pweb;
1|10|1
2|20|1
3|30|0
4|40|0
```

execute a column update:

```
sqlite> update pweb set h_id = _id;
```

See the changes to all rows:

```
sqlite> select * from pweb;
1|1|1
2|2|1
3|3|0
4|4|0
```

Something more complex ?

```
sqlite>  update pweb set h_id = _id + 1;
```

result:

```
sqlite> select * from pweb;
1|2|1
2|3|1
3|4|0
4|5|0
```

See also [Understanding SQLITE DataBase in Android](http://www.blazin.in/2016/02/understanding-sqlite-database-in-android.html):